# Are tables created by CTAS in aws athena an external table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, external-tables

Anyone who knows about the following, Please reply.

1. Are the Athena tables all external tables?
2. Aws Athena has external table and managed table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tables in Amazon Athena are 'external tables'. There is no concept of a 'managed table'.

However, unlike normal external tables in Presto, Amazon Athena also lets you `INSERT INTO` tables.